# Can you inherit the same class twice?

Tags: c++

Can you inherit the same class twice? E.g. :

```
class Base {

};

class Foo : public Base {

};

class Bar : public Base {

};

class Baz : public Foo, public Bar { 
    //is this legal? 
    // are there restrictions on Base 
    //       (e.g. only virtual methods or a virtual base)?

};
```

Comment: Yes, it's legal.  But as you have it right now, it often causes more problems than it solves.  (You'd want to at least use virtual base classes, for a couple of reasons.  Google "diamond problem".)

Comment: Don't forget to differentiate between dianond-problem with virtual bases and without.

Comment: Egads, as a public service message to SO users do mention what C++ book you are reading.  We'll have a bonfire with s'mores and warm our hands at the spectacle.  Always good when we learn something from you in return.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not using a book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is legal, and no there are no restrictions on `Base`.

You should however be aware that this causes two different objects of type `Base` to exist within `Baz`, which will require you to use qualified names to tell C++ which version of `Base` you mean, when you try to access its members.

C++ provides a mechanism called [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) to solve this problem (if it is a problem for you):

```
class Base { };

class Foo : public virtual Base { };

class Bar : public virtual Base { };

class Baz : public Foo, public Bar { };
```

This will share the `Base` object between the `Foo` and `Bar` objects within `Baz`

Answer (score 1):

C++ does support multiple inheritance.

The syntax for class Baz is correct.

See this tutorial for some caveats and more information: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal, but having two subobjects of the same Base class causes many difficulties, because you always must explicitly say which one you want, using the scope operator `::`.

```
Baz x;
Base& y = x; // Illegal because ambiguous.
Base& y = (Bar&)x; // Now unambiguous.
```

Part of that trouble can be solved by inheriting `Base` using virtual inheritance, which makes sure only exactly one `Base`.subobject exists.
In that case, the virtual base is always initialised by the most derived constructor, before all non-virtual bases.

```
class Base {}
class Foo : public virtual Base {}
class Bar : public virtual Base {}
class Baz : public Foo, public Bar {}

Baz x;
Base& y = x; // Legal, because even though both direct bases inherit from `Base`,
// they do so virtually, thus there is only one Base subobject
Base& y = (Bar&)x; // Still unambiguous.
```

Now, if `Foo` used protected or private inheritance, you could not cast down to Foo::Derived in Baz or completely outside in the first (non-virtual) example.
In the virtual example, you could, because that sub-object is also reachable using `Bar`, and the most accessible path determines the access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's legal to inherit the same class twice.

If the inheritance is non-virtual, as in your example (I just fixed the syntax and formatting),

```
class Base {};
class Foo : public Base {};
class Bar : public Base {};

class Baz : public Foo, public Bar {};
```

then it's generally necessary to qualify any use of something from such duplicate base.

If however each direct inheritance of the common base is virtual (using the keyword `virtual`), then there is only one common sub-object of the common base. This is the so called **diamond pattern** of inheritance in C++. It's a bit tricky, e.g. in that it yields at least one sub-object spread over a non-contiguous region of memory, and in that it's the most derived class that is responsible for initializing the common virtual base. Also it introduces some inefficiency and is associated with some compiler bugs. So it's seldom used, but sometimes it's necessary – e.g., it can emulate Java interface inheritance, and it can be used to emulate Java `final` (not necessary in C++11).

Answer (score 0):

This is legal.
But restrictions arise when classes are labeled protected and private classes before it. For this, its respective functions and attributes are protected and private.